# How can I support offline_access scope for an MS Identity app against public MSA?

Tags: azure-active-directory

The MS Identity website for MSA apps (http://apps.dev.microsoft.com)'s interface doesn't support adding the `offline_access` scope. How can I do this for my app?

Error:
AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope User.Read,offline_access is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you encountered:

> The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope User.Read,offline_access is not valid.

Your error is based on the request you constructed rather than the app config in the portal.  The problem here is the scopes should be separated by a single white space (%20 in web encoding).  In the error, it seems you have separated scopes with a comma.

Comment: Right you are, in our portal we were allowing scopes to be defined on separate lines, but inserting commas when we joined the lines together. If i put the scopes on the same line separated by a space, all is well. Thanks!